# Remove annotation from subtree commits (--unannotate) when Git subtree becomes a standalone repository

Tags: git, annotations, git-subtree, subtree

It's very useful to annotate subtree commits (whether manually or via `--annotate` option) to differentiate them from super repository or another subtree commits.

But if I want to export a subtree as a standalone repository, or push those commits to that already existing repository, it would be nice to remove that annotation, since it makes no sense when it no longer belongs to a subtree, but to a single repository.

Is there any way to remove the annotation in those cases?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way but to rewrite history with interactive rebase. `git subtree push` to a standalone repo, `git rebase -i` (in the standalone repo) to overwrite commit messages, `git push` from the standalone repo to an existing repo. Instead of interactive rebase you can use `git filter-branch --msg-filter` or `git filter-repo --message-callback`.